# Delphi: Can BinToHex() accepts a real binary number (base-2) in form of string in the first parameter?

Tags: delphi

## Overview

Luckily, Delphi has an RTL function that converts a binary value into its hexadecimal representation, namely [BinToHex()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.BinToHex), declared in `System.Classes` as follows:

```pascal
1.  procedure BinToHex(const Buffer: TBytes; BufOffset: Integer; var Text: TBytes; TextOffset: Integer; Count: Integer);
2.  procedure BinToHex(Buffer: PAnsiChar; Text: PAnsiChar; BufSize: Integer);
3.  procedure BinToHex(Buffer: PAnsiChar; Text: PWideChar; BufSize: Integer);
4.  procedure BinToHex(var Buffer; Text: PWideChar; BufSize: Integer);
5.  procedure BinToHex(var Buffer; Text: PAnsiChar; BufSize: Integer);
6.  procedure BinToHex(Buffer: Pointer; Text: PWideChar; BufSize: Integer);
7.  procedure BinToHex(Buffer: Pointer; Text: PAnsiChar; BufSize: Integer);
```

Delphi documentation states that the first parameter, i.e. `Buffer` is a pointer to **an array of bytes**. That means the function expects binary number passed as an array of bytes. Thus, one of possible way to convert binary to hexadecimal is as follows:

```pascal
procedure Test();
var
  aBinNum : TBytes;
  sHexNum : string;
  iBinSize: Integer;

begin
  aBinNum := TBytes.Create(255, 7); // An array of decimal numbers, right?
  iBinSize := Length(aBinNum) * 2;
  SetLength(sHexNum, iBinSize);
  BinToHex(aBinNum, PWideChar(sHexNum), iBinSize);
  WriteLn(sHexNum); // The output is FF07
end;
```

The problem with this approach is that the binary number **must be** written as decimal number because there is no such `0b11111111` `0b0111` [as in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants), for example.

Since the definition of [binary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) is a number expressed in the base-2 numeral system, I expect `BinToHex()` can receive a real base-2 number, maybe **in form of string**.

## Question

Is it possible to use the 3rd form of `BinToHex()` so that I can pass a real base-2 number to the function?

If that is not possible, probably `BinToHex()` should be renamed to `DecToHex()` or `BytesToHex()`. Just kidding. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BinToHex` is not intended to convert from a binary representation of an integer, as you are expecting. What it does is simply encode an array of bytes as hex. For instance. If you pass `BinToHex` the following bytes:

```
1, 2, 255
```

then `BinToHex` will encode that as:

```
0102ff
```

By binary what is meant is simply an array of bytes. It is not meant to indicate an integer represented in base 2.

You are looking for a function like this:

```
function Base2TextToInt(const Text: string): Cardinal;
var
  Index: Integer;
  Digit: Cardinal;
begin
  Digit := 1;
  Result := 0;
  for Index := Length(Text) downto 1 do
  begin
    case Text[Index] of
    '0':
      ; // do nothing
    '1':
      inc(Result, Digit);
    else
      raise EConvertError.CreateFmt('''%s'' is not a valid binary digit.', [Text[Index]]);
    end;
    Digit := Digit shl 1;
  end;
end;
```

Note that I have ignored the error case of there being more than 32 digits. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

---

One of the common misconceptions that people have is that a number can be a decimal number, or a binary number, and so on. Decimal, binary, etc. are just *representations* of a number. So, decimal `15` is equal to hex `f` is equal to binary `1111`. These are all the same number, represented differently.

Now, on a computer, if you want to differentiate between representations of a number, you do so with text. When you write:

```
i := 15;
j := $f;
```

you have assigned the same value to `i` and `j`. You can write

```
Assert(i = j);
```

If you are looking to enter a binary representation of a number into your source code, you are out of luck. Delphi supports decimal and hexadecimal representations only.

If you wish to convert a number to its binary representation, or vice versa, you use a function like the one I gave above. That function converts from a binary representation, stored in a string, to a number.

Comment: @David_Heffernan, than you very much for the details of straightening the misconception about decimal number, hexadecimal number, etc, as well as for the code snippet.

Comment: Note that Delphi in RAD Studio 11 now supports binary literals.  https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/What%27s_New